# Bind Key for Paperfold CSS

Tags: jquery, css, bind

I have a problem.

I downloaded the Paperfold CSS [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/paperfold-css) by mrflix and looked into the code.

I came across this passage:

```
// bind buttons
this.element.next('.seeMore').click( $.proxy(this, 'toggle') );
$('#go').click( $.proxy(this, 'toggle') );
```

I tried to change .seeMore to a.link because the paperfold should be triggered when I click a special link on the site, but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: So you mean you want to trigger on this.element.next('a.link').click()? If you place a break right after that line, what does this.element.next('a.link') contain?

Comment: Currently I have to click on a span with te class .seeMore. I'd like to change that to .link but then the animation doesn't start

Comment: @user1462382 You need to specify all the css styles `.seeMore` having to `a.link` in order to view the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('.link').click( $.proxy(this, 'toggle') );
```

And you can remove quite some code that is used for the demo interaction (sliders, the go button `$('#go')` - all code you don't need).

Comment: Is it possible to show me which code exactly I can erase? I don't want to break the whole thing ;)
I just would like to use the toggle animation if I click on a specific button

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `a:link` instead of `a.link`?

If I do `document.getElementsByClassName('link')`, there is only an element with class `link`, and is a `li` element instead of `a`.

**Edit**:

Ah, it was an example!

So here you have the solution:

If you look at the code, the button which starts the animation has the id `go` and has no class. So changing `.seeMore` you won't have an anchor which works as that button.

You have to change the last line of the code you posted:

```
$('#go').click( $.proxy(this, 'toggle') );
```

into

```
$('a.link').click( $.proxy(this, 'toggle') );
```

Comment: The Paperfold Animation should be triggered when I click an anchor with the class "link" (just an example)